# Windows 7 XP mode fonts too small

Tags: windows-7, fonts, windows-xp-mode

Is there any way to increase the system font size in XP mode? I need it at least 100% larger to read anything. The setting for font size appears to be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this thread: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7performance/thread/ce6c7c6a-dc13-417f-bc6d-8b4cc54e771e
A workaround would be to use Magnifier.